# Error when trying to get a click event on wms layer

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to check if wms layer was clicked on, when i try to send the point that was clicked i get this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://x.x.x.x:x/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="InvalidPoint">
      365, 315 not in dimensions of image: 1343, 0
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Why this happens?

The HTML code:

```
map.events.register('click', map, findFeaturesAtLocationOnClick);           // Register users click



function findFeaturesAtLocationOnClick(event) {



                mouseLocation = map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy);



                var url = events.getFullRequestString({

                                                                REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",

                                                                EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",

                                                                BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),

                                                                X: event.xy.x,

                                                                Y: event.xy.y,

                                                                INFO_FORMAT: 'text/plain',

                                                                QUERY_LAYERS: 'events',

                                                                FEATURE_COUNT: 100,

                                                                WIDTH: map.size.w,

                                                                HEIGHT: map.size.h},

                                                                wmsURL);



                OpenLayers.loadURL(url, '', this, setPopupHTML);

}



function setPopupHTML(response) {



                // In this function, the response contains the exception I mentioned above

}
```

Comment: What client app or method are you using when you receive this error?

Comment: @artwork21 updated my question

Comment: Looks like the client code is from the [geoserver-users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/28164969/), there's a solution there

Comment: The error in the referred case was in X and Y parameters but in this case it seems that HEIGHT is set to zero.